# Is there a way to save Bokeh plot from QWebView?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, bokeh

I'm displaing Bokeh plot in `QWebView`, but unfortunately `save` button at the Bokeh plot toolbar doesn't work (when I display the same plot in browser everything is fine). Other Bokeh buttons in `QWebView` are operational.  How do I make `save` button work in `QWebView`?

```
# plt_file is temporary html-file with html generated by Bokeh
plt_file.seek(0)
self.plot_web_view.setContent(plt_file.read())
```

Comment: `QWebView` might require you to write a custom save tool that does something slightly different. Fortunately, [Bokeh is extensible](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) Alternatively, the save tool only has [a few lines of code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/tools/actions/save_tool.coffee) perhaps you can tell from looking at it what operation `QWebView ` does not support.

Comment: I should add, those links are for current (`0.12.2`) releases. It's always advised to include relevant version information.